# greedy operator in regular expression is not working in Tcl 8.5

Tags: regex, perl, tcl, regex-greedy

See this simple regexp code:

```
puts [ regexp -inline {^\-\-\S+?=\S+} "--tox=9.0" ]
```

The output is:

```
 >--tox=9
```

It would seem that the second \S+ is being non-greedy! Only 1 character is being matched
In PERL, one can can see that the result is as I expected, see 1 line output:

```
perl -e '"--tox=9.0" =~/(^\-\-\S+?=\S+)/ ; print "${1}\n"'
--tox=9.0
```

How can I get the Perl behaviour in Tcl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an inherent 'feature' of Tcl's regexp implementation. For instance, the [below](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.tcl/FddeFPbTFw8/asoMuv7dWqIJ) is from Henry Spencer (the one who did most if not all of Tcl's regexp work I believe)

> It is very difficult to come up with an entirely satisfactory
>   definition of the behavior of mixed-greediness regular expressions. 
>   Perl doesn't try:  the Perl "specification" is a description of the
>   implementation, an inherently low-performance approach involving
>   trying one match at a time. This is unsatisfactory for a number of
>   reasons, not least being that it takes several pages of text merely to
>   describe it.  (That implementation and its description are distant,
>   mutated descendants of one of my earlier regexp packages, so I share
>   some of the blame for this.)
>
> When all quantifiers are greedy, the Tcl 8.2 regexp matches the
>   longest possible match (as specified in the POSIX standard's
>   regular-expression definition).  When all are non-greedy, it matches
>   the shortest possible match.  Neither of these desirable statements is
>   true of Perl.
>
> The trouble is that it is very, very hard to write a generalization of
>   those statements which covers mixed-greediness regular expressions --
>   a proper, implementation-independent definition of what
>   mixed-greediness regular expressions *should* match -- and makes them
>   do "what people expect".  I've tried.  I'm still trying.  No luck so
>   far.
>
> The rules in the Tcl 8.2 regexp, which basically give the whole regexp
>   a long/short preference based on its subexpressions, are the best I've
>   come up with so far.  The code implements them accurately.  I agree
>   that they fall short of what's really wanted.  It's trickier than it
>   looks.

Basically, expressions with mixed greedy and non-greedy quantifiers impacts both the simplicity of the implementation and the performance. So, the implementation makes it so that the first 'type' of quantifier is passed on to all other quantifiers.

In other words, if the first quantifier is greedy, all the others will be greedy. If the first is non-greedy, all the others will be non-greedy. And therefore, you cannot force a Tcl regexp to work like a Perl regexp (or maybe you can through `exec` and using the bash command version of perl, but I'm not familiar with this).

I would advise using negated classes and/or anchors instead of non-greedy.

Since I don't know the exact context of your question, I won't provide an alternative regexp, because that will depend on whether this is really the whole string you are trying to make a match on.

Answer (score 3):

The Tcl regular expression engine is an automata-theoretic one instead of a stack-based one, so it has a *very* different approach to matching mixed greediness REs. In particular, for the sort of RE you're talking about, that will be interpreted as entirely non-greedy.

The simplest method of fixing this is to use a different RE. Remembering that `\S` is just a shorthand for `[^\s]`, we can do this (excluding `=` from the first part):

```
puts [ regexp -inline {^--[^\s=]+=\S+} "--tox=9.0" ]
```

(I also changed `\-` to `-` as it's not a special character in Tcl's REs.)

Comment: You could also get the effect by rebuilding Tcl to use PCRE rather than its own RE engine, but that's a lot more work and will change many other things subtly besides.

Answer (score 2):

The answer can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.tcl/FddeFPbTFw8/asoMuv7dWqIJ):

> Unfortunately, the answer is that to get the same answer Perl gives,
>   you have to use Perl's exact regexp implementation.

In your case, I'd use both anchors, `^` and `$`:

```
  puts [ regexp -inline {^\-\-\S+?=\S+$} "--tox=9.0" ]
```

The result is: `--tox=9.0`